# Surprisingly, it's no surprise

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

Surprisingly, it's no surprise,
To find the truth in all my lies,
When fast asleep with open eyes,
I'm breathless as I breathe.

I whisper, as I scream at you,
“I'm overjoyed at feeling blue,”
I'm joking, but I mean it too,
And enter as I leave.

What am I?

Hint:

> Not an oxymoron or paradox, but similar.

Comment: The title, typo or hint ?

Comment: @Menace Haha, true riddler :D

Comment: @nicael Hehe :D

But it was just typo :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also be

> A contradiction (or contrary)?
> a list of opposing statements - contradiction - self explanatory?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> An oxymoron!  (Self explanatory?)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it's no surprise,

To find the truth in all my lies,

> Sometimes your mind can deceive you, but ultimately you can't knowingly lie to yourself, so there is always truth.

When fast asleep with open eyes,

I'm breathless as I breathe.

> Thoughts come at all times of day, even in the subconscious.

I whisper, as I scream at you,

“I'm overjoyed and feeling blue,”

> Thoughts are silent, but they can seem loud.

I'm joking, but I mean it too,

And enter as I leave.

> Some thoughts are personal jokes (think sassy), and when they leave your mind they might enter the 'real world'.

What am I?

> A thought

Comment: Apologies, my internet is temperamental sometimes and it mustn't have gone through properly

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously

> A Paradox!!!

Comment: Please explain your answer further so we can see more of your thought process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> An antonym?

Because...

> Antonym means "opposite", which is what every line contains a pair of.